# SPARQL in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-recommendation

Is there any open source application for Ubuntu/Linux that can handle SPARQL to perform queries over RDF stores and knowledge graphs? It doesn't necessarily have to be within apt, may as well be from another source. Any would do.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man3/RDF::Query.3pm.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used it but, [Morla](http://morlardf.net/screenshots/) may help.

From its [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=morla) description:

> Description-en: GTK+ RDF editor
> With Morla you can manage more RDF
> documents simultaneously, visualize  graphs, use templates for quick
> writing and exec SPARQL/RDQL queries.  .  You can import RDFS
> documents and use their content to write new RDF  triples. Templates
> are also RDF documents, and they make Morla easily  customizable and
> expandable. You can embed Javascript code in your  templates so you
> can validate and change user inputs.  .  Morla is also a modular
> software so you can add functionality to the  save, open and view
> procedures.  .  You can also use Morla as an RDF navigator, wandering
> among the net  knots of the RDF documents present on internet exactly
> as we are used  to do with web browsers.

It is installable with

```
sudo apt-get install morla
```

Comment: The link to Morla doesn't work

Comment: Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two frameworks that I can think of: [RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/) and [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/). They are both open source and multi-platform (since they are written in Java) and can run in Ubuntu too.

There is also a similar question in [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10119/query-rdf-with-sparql).